# jQuery Validation: Avoid validating on first attempt

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin and it automatically validates the moment user types something & I want to keep this functionality but avoid it when user fills the field on first attempt.

I am using it on credit card number field so it is annoying that text field becomes all red even when user haven't finished typing the entire card.

**What i have tried:**

I have added a class which blocks the error class formatting and that class is removed when at least one time focus event have occurred.

```
    // This is the focus event that removes the 'no-error-first-attempt' class
    $('.js-ccvalidate input').focusout(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('no-error-first-attempt')){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('no-error-first-attempt');
        }
    });
```

This solution works however if the user press submit button directly then the focus event haven't been performed hence the error visual cue don't show up... I can make function and bind it to submit button but this all looks terribly wrong... is there a better approach to this problem?

**EDIT**

This question is not the same as "[How to perform validation on submit only - jQuery Validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599865/how-to-perform-validation-on-submit-only-jquery-validation-plugin)" as i want to keep the "onfocusout", "onkeyup" & "onclick" values to true but just not one the first attempt of users.

Comment: nope i want to keep the validation on key press event but on on first attempt.

Comment: But that plugin only validates on `blur` if I'm not wrong. It does `onkeyup` only after the error is shown. Do you want it not to do that as well before the user clicks on `submit`?

Comment: hmm you are right just checked the demo... it is working fine.. may be something is wrong in the theme i am using...

Comment: Found a solution thanks @Салман

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the functionality that i was looking for was already there in plugin however I was using a theme which was defining this:

```
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            var parent = $(element).closest('.form-group');
            if(event.keyCode == 9){
                return false;
            }
            if ($(element).valid()) {
                parent.removeClass('has-error');
                parent.next('.error').remove();
            }
        },
```

I simply changed it to this:

```
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            var parent = $(element).closest('.form-group');
            if(event.keyCode == 9){
                return false;
            }
            if ($(element).is('[aria-invalid]')){   
                if ($(element).valid()) {
                    parent.removeClass('has-error');
                    parent.next('.error').remove();
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
```

Now the text field is not validated on first attempt :)